# Get author image from corresponding article in thumbnail

Tags: post-thumbnails, author

I want to add an author image for each thumbnail-preview on my homepage.

I tried `<?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ), 32 ); ?>` but it gives me the same image in every thumbnail.

Here's the full code for the thumbnails:

```
 <?php
          $recentp_args = array( 'numberposts' => '4' );
          $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts($recentp_args);
          foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){ ?>
            <article>
              <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($recent["ID"]); ?>">
                <?php 
                  $thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail( $recent["ID"], 'featuredmedium', array( 'class' => 'lazyload' ) );
                  if ( !empty($thumb) ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
                    echo $thumb;
                  } else {
                    echo '<img src="'.get_bloginfo('template_url').'/images/photo_default.png" width="320" height="167" alt="" />';
                  }
                ?>
                <h2 class="title"><?php echo $recent["post_title"]; ?></h2>
                <?php echo apply_filters( 'the_content', limit_words(strip_tags($recent["post_content"]),38) ); ?>

                <?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ), 32 ); ?>
              </a>
            </article>
        <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong here `<?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ), 32 ); ?>` won't work because you're not in [The Loop](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/).  If you want to use functions that don't take a specific post ID but use the global post you need to be in the loop.  instead of using a foreach you need to us a standard wordpress post loop, which also means you need to get the posts as a query object instead of an array. Change your recent posts line to `$recent_posts = new WP_Query($recentp_args);` and replace your foreach loop with the following

```
if ($recent_posts->have_posts()) : 
    while $recent_posts->have_posts(): 
        $recent_posts->the_post;
```

Then `get_the_author_meta()` should work.

Comment: Here's what I changed it to, but it's giving me this error **Call to a member function have_posts() on array**

`<?php
    $recentp_args = array( 'numberposts' => '4' );
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts($recentp_args, OBJECT);
          if ( $recent_posts->have_posts() ) {
 while ( $recent_posts->have_posts() ) {
  $recent_posts->the_post(); 
    ?>
    
            <article> ... </article>
<?php }
} ?>`

Comment: okay I guess `wp_get_recent_posts` won't return a query object like that.  Edited the solution to use `new WP_Query`  you may need to add orderby and order args but I think the default is by date descending which should get you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'ID') , 150); ?>
```

Is exactly what I use.

I think the issue is with "foreach( $recent_posts as $recent )", I recommend using

```
if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) :
```

I recommend checking out https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/ and remember to reset the loop with after your done

```
wp_reset_postdata();
```